# how to load image in ImageButton in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to create my imagebutton in code behind. so i use this code:

```
 LiteralControl ltr = new LiteralControl();

 ltr.Text = "<asp:ImageButton class=\"stylImage\" AlternateText=\"Signature\" runat=\"server\" ImageUrl=\"~/images/Workflow/digital-signature-pic.jpg\" OnCommand=\"Image_OnCommand\" CommandName=\"imgclick\"/>";
```

but it doesn't work. nothing display.

Any Idea?!

Comment: Make a new instance of `ImageButton` like @chridam and @Bex do and add that object to a placeholder or panel. Do that in the `Page_Init`method.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a Literal control, add a panel control and include the ImageButton control in your panel. You should add the controls in the Page Init event

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton();
    imgBtn.ID = "img_id";
    imgBtn.ImageUrl = "~/images/Workflow/digital-signature-pic.jpg";
    imgBtn.AlternateText= "Signature";
    imgBtn.Click += (source, args) =>
    {
        // do something
    };
    Panel1.Controls.Add(imgBtn);
}
```

Comment: i've tried this. but the image does not load?! but when i use my code in directly in asp.net (not codebehind) the image load perfectly!

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the Page Init event that you should add the control in.

Comment: it works when i add my imagebutton in a panel. but when i add it in a table cell id doesn't work?! this is my code :  HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();
-- Creating image button as u said --cell.Controls.Add(img);
cell.InnerText = "StatusName";
row.Cells.Add(cell);   the text "StatusName" is shown, but there is no image!!!
tblStatus.Rows.Add(row);

Comment: You created a table cell called cell1 here HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell(); but you are adding the ImageButton control to another table cell called cell, not cell1.

Comment: it was just a mistyping, in real code both have the same name (cell).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to a container on the page, see this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx

Comment: i'm working in a web user control. and i add the imagebutton in a table cell. should i use Placeholder?!?!

Answer (score 0):

You can't write a server side control to a literal.
You have two options,

- either set the image button directly on the page and change the visibility attribute
- Or Add a placeholder or panel control and dynamically add the image button to it, something like this

  ```
          ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(); 
          btn.ImageUrl = "my image url";

          btn.Click += btn_Click;

          btn.ID = "create an ID";
          etc....
          ph.Controls.Add(btn);
  ```